Adding earthquake data and map for Fiji
I used the datasets::quakes to plot the earthquakes on Fiji like that:
quakes_df <- datasets::quakes
library(ggplot2)
my_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data= quakes_df, aes(lat, long, col= mag)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low= "green", high= "red", na.value= "black", aesthetics= "colour", 
                   breaks= seq(min(quakes_df$mag), max(quakes_df$mag), length.out= 4))
my_plot


In the next step I want to add the polygons for Fiji in order to better understand where the earthquakes actually happen. But so far I cant figure out how to combine both plots. What I do is:
# Data of whole world
world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
# Extract Fiji only.
fiji <- subset(world, sovereignt == "Fiji", select= "geometry")
# Add new layer to existing plot
my_plot + geom_sf(data= fiji)


The resulting plot is wrong. What is happening here? And how can I add Fijis country borders onto the first plot with the earthquakes?

You can use the package sf to transform your df as  geospatial object sf ex with sf::st_as_sf(). You could then use geom_sf()  instead of geom_point().

You can use the package sf to transform your dataframe as a geospatial object sf ex.  with sf::st_as_sf(). The data seems to be expressed in longitude-latitude; probably in the coordinate reference systeme (CRS) EPSG:4326 . Since it's around the 180­deg line,  this answer suggest to use the CRS EPSG:3994 (disclamer: I am not familiar with the CRS of the Pacific area).
I added Australia on the map for more spatial context.
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

quakes_df <- datasets::quakes
world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
fiji <- subset(world, sovereignt == "Fiji", select= "geometry")
Australia <- subset(world, sovereignt == "Australia", select= "geometry")

quakes_sf <- st_as_sf(quakes_df , coords =c ("long","lat") , crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_transform(crs=3994)

ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data= fiji %>% st_transform(crs=3994))+
  geom_sf(data= Australia %>% st_transform(crs=3994))+
  geom_sf(data= quakes_sf, aes(col= mag),alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_color_gradient(low= "green", high= "red", na.value= "black", aesthetics= "colour", 
                       breaks= seq(min(quakes_df$mag), max(quakes_df$mag), length.out= 4))


Created on 2024-07-10 with reprex v2.1.0

I believe that st_transform(crs=3994) is what I was missing most. Thanks!

After a second look, your first difficulty is that you interverted x and y. You can achieve a decent plot with geom_point(data= quakes_df, aes(x= long, y = lat,col= mag) instead of st_as_sf and geom_sf(data=quakes_sf), but the transition at 180deg will still be an issue.

Roughly 90% of this figure does not carry useful information.

@Friede This is true but not an issue to me since now I know the principle of combining the layers and can choose what part I want to display

Perhaps mapping quakes over bathymetry layer (sans Australia), but as you say, your map.

I do not think so: "I want to add the polygons for Fiji".

I would rather focus on Fiji, i.e.
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth) # devtools::install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearthhires")
library(ggplot2)

# Note: 
sum(is.na(quakes$mag)) # na.value="black"
#> [1] 0
quakes = 
  st_as_sf(quakes, coords=c("long","lat"), crs=4326) |> 
  st_transform(crs=3994)
Fiji = 
  ne_countries(scale="large", returnclass="sf") |>
  subset(sovereignt=="Fiji", select=c("geometry")) |>
  st_transform(crs=3994)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=Fiji) +
  geom_sf(data=quakes, aes(col=mag), alpha=.05) +
  scale_color_gradient(low="green", high="red", aesthetics="colour", 
                       breaks=seq( min(quakes$mag), max(quakes$mag), length.out=4L )) +
  coord_sf(st_bbox(quakes)[c(1L, 3L)], st_bbox(quakes)[c(2L, 4L)])


